# d3.js data missing, how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I use data() to draw lines as many as data.length, but it doesn't work. But if I change lint to circle element, the element number is right. I don't know how to fix it.

```
inner_svg
.selectAll('line')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('line')
```

The code just draws 28 lines, but the data.length is 44.

```
inner_svg
.selectAll('circle')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('circle')
```

If I change the code, then it draws 44 circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because you already have 16 lines in the SVG.

> ## selection.enter()
>
> Returns the enter selection: placeholder nodes for each datum that had
>   **no corresponding DOM element** in the selection. (The enter selection is
>   empty for selections not returned by selection.data.)

Snippet which demonstrates the issue:-

```js
var data = [1,2,3,4,5];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

// svg.selectAll('line') returns two existing lines.

svg.selectAll('line')
.data(data)
.enter() //Appends 5-2=3 lines
.append('line')
.attr("x1",10)
.attr("x2",100)
.attr("y1",function(d,i){ return (i+1)*50; })
.attr("y2",function(d,i){ return (i+1)*50; });
```

```css
line{
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg height=400 width=400>
  <!-- Two lines -->
  <line x1=10 x2=10 y1=0 y2=30></line>
  <line x1=30 x2=30 y1=0 y2=30></line>
</svg>
```

The best way to resolve such issues is using a more narrow selector. For example, you can add a specific class for the new lines as shown below and use it as a selector.

```
 svg.selectAll('.link') //Select by class name
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('line')
    .attr("class","link") //Adding class link
    .attr("x1",10)
    .attr("x2",100)
    .attr("y1",function(d,i){ return (i+1)*50; })
    .attr("y2",function(d,i){ return (i+1)*50; });
```

```js
var data = [1,2,3,4,5];

var svg = d3.select("svg");


svg.selectAll('.link')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('line')
.attr("class","link")
.attr("x1",10)
.attr("x2",100)
.attr("y1",function(d,i){ return (i+1)*50; })
.attr("y2",function(d,i){ return (i+1)*50; });
```

```css
line{
  stroke: black;
}

.link{
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg height=400 width=400>
  <!-- Two lines -->
  <line x1=10 x2=10 y1=0 y2=30></line>
  <line x1=30 x2=30 y1=0 y2=30></line>
</svg>
```

Comment: Glad the solution worked. Would you mind accepting this answer? It might help people experiencing a similar issue.